# factrorize $-a^3+a^2b+a^2c+ab^2-2abc+ac^2-b^3+b^2c+bc^2-c^3$

Tags: factoring

factrorize $-a^3+a^2b+a^2c+ab^2-2abc+ac^2-b^3+b^2c+bc^2-c^3$

or
$$ -(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) + (a^2 b + a b^2 + b^2 c + b c^2 + c^2 a + c a^2) - 2(abc)  $$

It is a so long polynomial I don't have any ideas for starting factoring what should I do?

Comment: Assuming it _can_ be factored, it looks to me very much like the product of three factors of the form $(\pm a \pm b \pm c)$, perhaps one of $a, b, c$ is lacking from one of the factors as well. Try playing around with that, and see what you get.

Comment: is there a typo in you term? twice $a^2b$?

Answer (score 1):

$$   ( a +b - c)  ( b + c - a )  ( c + a - b)  $$
This is one factor short of [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula#Formulation),
$$  (a + b + c)  ( a +b - c)  ( b + c - a )  ( c + a - b) = 2 (b^2 c^2 + c^2 a^2 + a^2 b^2) - (a^4 + b^4 + c^4)  $$