# Factoring $a^2b+a^2c+ab^2+b^2c+ac^2+bc^2−a^3−b^3−c^3−2abc$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I factor the expression below only using basic factoring techniques without symmetric polynomials? thank you in advance.

$$a^2b+a^2c+ab^2+b^2c+ac^2+bc^2−a^3−b^3−c^3−2abc$$

I had found the question in another topic, but the answer doesn't quite explain how to make a more basic form [[factrorize $-a^3+a^2b+a^2c+ab^2-2abc+ac^2-b^3+b^2c+bc^2-c^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011819/factrorize-a3a2ba2cab2-2abcac2-b3b2cbc2-c3?r=SearchResults) ].

Comment: My first thought:  what does the expansion of $(a+b+c) ^3$ look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you "know" that there is a nice factorization, then because it is symmetric in 3 variables and has degree 3, it can only be one of the following (or their multiples):

$$ \prod (a+b-c), (a+b+c)^3 , (a+b+c)\left( k(a^2+b^2+c^2) + l (ab+bc+ca)\right) $$

We can then expand all of these and compare.

---

As related examples, try to factorize the following knowing that a nice factorization exists:

1. $a^3+b^3+c^3 - 3abc$
2. $a^4+b^4+c^4 + a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2 -2abc(a+b+c)$

Comment: That´s cheating, because you first use the fact that nice factorization exists.

Comment: That's my point (if you can't tell from the first line).

Comment: I know, but it can also be done differently.

Comment: Of course, so add in your approach. I was thinking of doing the "remainder-factor" way, but that also seems to be an after-the-fact justification.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2690926/determination-of-the-algebraic-image-of-a-polynomial-morphism/2694033#2694033   about less nice factors (of a homogeneous ternary cubic) and example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678486/how-to-show-that-if-x-y-z-are-rational-numbers-satisfying-x-y-z3-9/2678675#2678675